# PyMC3 Multinomial Model doesn't work with non-integer observe data

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

I'm trying to use PyMC3 to solve a fairly simple multinomial distribution.  It works perfectly if I have the 'noise' value set to 0.0.  However when I change it to anything else, for example 0.01, I get an error in the `find_MAP()` function and it hangs if I don't use `find_MAP()`.

Is there some reason that the multinomial has to be sparse?

```
import numpy as np
from pymc3 import *
import pymc3 as mc
import pandas as pd
print 'pymc3 version: ' + mc.__version__


sample_size = 10
number_of_experiments = 1


true_probs = [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4]


k = len(true_probs)


noise = 0.0
y = np.random.multinomial(n=number_of_experiments, pvals=true_probs, size=sample_size)+noise
y_denominator = np.sum(y,axis=1)
y = y/y_denominator[:,None]


with Model() as multinom_test:
    probs = Dirichlet('probs', a = np.ones(k), shape = k)
    for i in range(sample_size):
        data = Multinomial('data_%d' % (i),
                           n = y[i].sum(),
                           p = probs,
                           observed = y[i])


with multinom_test:
    start = find_MAP()
    trace = sample(5000, Slice())
trace[probs].mean(0)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Optimization error: max, logp or dlogp at max have non-
finite values. Some values may be outside of distribution support. 
max: {'probs_stickbreaking_': array([  0.00000000e+00,  -4.47034834e- 
08,   0.00000000e+00])} logp: array(-inf) dlogp: array([  
0.00000000e+00,   2.98023221e-08,   0.00000000e+00])Check that 1) you 
don't have hierarchical parameters, these will lead to points with 
infinite density. 2) your distribution logp's are properly specified. 
Specific issues:
```

Comment: Try writing the likelihood like: 
```data_pred = pm.Multinomial('data_pred',n=number_of_experiments, p=a, observed=y)```

you can also try using Metropolis instead of Slice

Comment: Hi aloctavodia, I'm not even getting to the sample step so I don't think it's a problem with Metropolis vs. Slice.  Can you clarify your likelihood function?  I have several columns so I'm using the array notation [i].  Are you suggesting there is another way of doing this operation?

Comment: Sorry, when I made my comment I was assuming that by passing ```p=a``` and then  ```y``` to the likelihood ```a``` will be correctly broadcasted. In fact the models runs, but the samples seems to become only from the prior, that is they seem to be non affected by the likelihood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```py
sample_size = 10
number_of_experiments = 100

true_probs = [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4]
k = len(true_probs)
noise = 0.01
y = np.random.multinomial(n=number_of_experiments, pvals=true_probs, size=sample_size)+noise

with pm.Model() as multinom_test:
    a = pm.Dirichlet('a', a=np.ones(k))
    for i in range(sample_size):
        data_pred = pm.Multinomial('data_pred_%s'% i, n=number_of_experiments, p=a, observed=y[i])
    trace = pm.sample(50000, pm.Metropolis())
    #trace = pm.sample(1000) # also works with NUTS

pm.traceplot(trace[500:]);
```

[image: traceplot]

Comment: This works.  It seems that the problem with my code was setting n=y[i].sum() .  I have no idea why this matters since that provides the same value as number_of_experiments, but now it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Notice that ```y[i].sum() = number_of_experiments``` only for ```noise = 0```.